# A way to print out the times of events in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ping

I have been having some issues with my internet dropping out every 10-15 minutes for around 3-5 seconds. With a simple `ping www.google.com -t` I can see various instances of:

```
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
```

Is there a way to print out the time of the system clock at these events? It doesn't matter if the time is printed on the regular ping responses as well.

Comment: This is what I get without the -t option:

ping www.google.com;

PING www.google.com (172.217.4.196) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga15s48-in-f196.1e100.net (172.217.4.196): icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=159 ms
64 bytes from lga15s48-in-f196.1e100.net (172.217.4.196): icmp_seq=2 ttl=52 time=142 ms
64 bytes from lga15s48-in-f196.1e100.net (172.217.4.196): icmp_seq=3 ttl=52 time=145 ms;

Why do you use -t? I can't find it on the man pages of ping.

Comment: `ping www.google.com` will ping 4 times. `ping www.google.com -t` will ping until you tell it to stop.

Comment: `-t` is a Windows thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the Windows Ping command has no built in function to date and timestamp the result of each ping, with a bit of effort you can get it to do that, handy if you specifically need to use the Windows Ping command. You can get more info on that website.

https://www.raymond.cc/blog/timestamp-ping-with-hrping/

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: If anyone is interested, the command on that website is:
`ping -t www.google.com|cmd /q /v /c "(pause&pause)>nul & for /l %%a in () do (set /p "data=" && echo(!date! !time! !data!)&ping -n 2 www.google.com>nul" >C:\pingtest.txt`

Which puts a text file on your C drive with the ongoing results.